# How to add a List of integers and a List of Triples into a HashMap in java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, hashmap

I want to write a code to put `(List<Integer> , List<Triple>)` as a (key, value) into a `HashMap` : `Map <List<Integer> , List<Triples>> ptList = new HashMap<>();` Triples are three integer values. for a pattern like (1,3) I have a location list like (0,0,1) I want to check if the pattern is not in the `ptList` if it was not there then I put it into the key part and the triple into the value part.

```
pattern =new ArrayList<>();    
pattern.add(first);
pattern.add(second);
sequenceID = sequence.getId();

//Generate triples with sequence ID and start with end
if (!ptList.containsKey(pattern)) {
     location=new ArrayList<>();
     Triples triples = new Triples(sequenceID, i, j);
     location.add(triples);
}
```

till now there is no problem, but when a new pattern is coming and it's in the `ptList` I want to add a new triple to the value part of the map without changing the key part.

For example `[[1,3]= (0,0,1)]` is stored in the hashMap, then another `[1,3]` is occurred with a different triple say `(1,3,4)` I want to add `(1,3,4)` to the previous list such as `[1,3]=[(0,0,1),(1,3,4)]`
So that's how I know that pattern `[1,3]` occurred two times in two different locations. How can I do that? What is the else part to add the triple into the `List<Triples>` and keep the old location?

Comment: Will your key pattern always be two numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be like this

```
if (!ptList.containsKey(pattern)) {
     location=new ArrayList<>();
     Triples triples = new Triples(sequenceID, i, j);
     location.add(triples);
}else{
    location=new ArrayList<>();
    Triples triples = new Triples(sequenceID, i, j);
    ptList.get(pattern).add(triples);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the key `(1,3)` exists in the map, if negative, `put(key, new ArrayList with triple)` otherwise, `get(key).add(triple)`

Or use 3rd part lib, e.g. Guava's `Multimap` to simplify your logic.

after all, I feel there could be room to improve your design. but I am not sure, because don't know your requirement exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a MultiMap and there are existing implementations you can use such as the [Apache Commons Collections MultiValueMap decorator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/index.html) or the [Guava Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). Note that the signature changes from `Map <List<Integer> , List<Triple>>` to `Map <List<Integer> , Triple>`.

Alternatively, you can do this yourself as the others have posted.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do use a List for a key in hash map data structure. The content of List may change and then your map will be in invalid state.

```
public void store(Collection<Integer> key, Collection<Triple> value) {

    Integer rank = rank(key);

    put(rank,value);
}

public Collection<Triple> retrieve(Collection<Integer> key) {

    Integer rank = rank(key);

    return storage.get(rank);

} 

private void put(Integer rank, Collection<Triple> value) {

    if(!storage.contains(rank)) {
       storage.put(rank,new ArrayList<>());
    }

    storage.get(rank).add(value)
}
```

The function rank should create a value that would be able to identify the list.

Answer (score 0):

Since your pattern is dynamic in size, I would suggest creating your own object to represent this pattern. This way it can be wrapped up and you can avoid using the list object as your key. Then use [Guava's ArrayListMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html).

```
ArrayListMultimap<Pattern, Triple> myMap = ArrayListMultumap.create();
```

And you can simply put values for a particular key pair. This also accepts duplicate values. If you don't want that then use [HashMultimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultimap.html).

Comment: No , My patterns are not fixed size. They will get bigger because I want to create longer patterns later.

Comment: Can you create an object for that to wrap it up so that the map doesn't need to have a list object as key.

Comment: actually I tried that pair idea but didn't work, I tried to create a class for my patterns in a way that each time I call Pattern it can take as many integers as I need. but I couldn't do that for now